# Using OnMouseDown to collect an item

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a cookie clicker clone, and I want to make it so as you press the cookie it gives you cookie (as a currency), but it gives me the message:

> error CS0103: The name `OnMouseDown' does not exist in the current context.

Then I also want it to display the current amount of cookies. Any help on how to achieve that?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Clickable : MonoBehaviour {

    public int cookie;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        OnMouseDown();
        cookie += 1;

    }
}
```

new code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Clickable : MonoBehaviour {

    public int cookie;

    void OnMouseDown();
    cookie += 1;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

}
```

Comment: You're not implementing OnMouseDown.

Answer (score 1):

You don't call `OnMouseDown()` like that, you need to implement it with your class like so:

```
void OnMouseDown() {
    cookie += 1;
}
```

More info here: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html

Comment: yea.. I did that in the first place, gives me the message: error CS1547: Keyword `void' cannot be used in this context.

and also: error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `(', expecting `)', `,', `;', `[', or `='

Comment: Were you extending it outside `Update()`?

Comment: no i did not.. now i placed it under "public int cookie;" and got the message: error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `+=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: post your new code. You are getting syntax errors and those are hard to troubleshoot without seeing the code.

Comment: I put it on the bottom of the post

Comment: That isn't how you extend or even create a function. Look at my answer again, your error should be easy for you to spot.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting for accuracy that you're not "extending" anything because of the way Unity works. You just implement the function as a private member and Unity will call it if present.

Comment: @DanPuzey You are right, I have changed the wording in my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.